# Comparing Cell Values to Activate Msgbox

Tags: vba, excel

Having macro issues. VBA beginner. Have a situation where:

```
Column D    Column E
3           2
```

And I just want to make sure the user doesn't enter anything in column D that exceed column E. If so, a message box pops up and tells the user the issue.

The code below works for cells D4 / E4, but having trouble making it work for every cell onwards if I want to compare D5 to E5, D6 to E6 and so on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("D4") > Range("E4") Then
        MsgBox "Discount too high"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important that you use the `Target` object. It represents the changed cell(s)

- Check that `Target` is in column `D`
- Loop through the `Target` cells to avoid errors when you paste to/update multiple cells
- Use `Offset` to get to column `E`

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    If Intersect(Target, Range("D:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In Target
        If Intersect(Range("D:D"), r.EntireRow).Value > Intersect(Range("E:E"), r.EntireRow).Value And Intersect(Range("E:E"), r.EntireRow) <> vbNullString Then s = s & ", " & r.Address
    Next r
    If s <> vbNullString Then MsgBox "Discount too high in cells: " & Mid(s, 3)
End Sub
```

---

**Update for "same" cells**

This will also capture cells with the same discount rates

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, d As Range, e As Range
    Dim high As String, same As String, s As String

    If Intersect(Target, Range("D:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In Target
        Set d = Intersect(Range("D:D"), r.EntireRow)
        Set e = Intersect(Range("E:E"), r.EntireRow)
        If d.Value > e.Value And e.Value <> vbNullString Then high = high & ", " & r.Address
        If d.Value = e.Value And e.Value <> vbNullString Then same = same & ", " & r.Address
    Next r
    If high <> vbNullString Then s = "Discount too high in cells: " & Mid(high, 3)
    If same <> vbNullString Then
        If s <> vbNullString Then s = s & vbCrLf
        s = s & "Discount the same in cells: " & Mid(same, 3)
    End If

    If s <> vbNullString Then MsgBox s, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Would be cool if you add to message box what cell is too high. Something like `MsgBox "Discount too high in" & Target.Address(False, False)`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, nice idea! I expanded on in my edited answer :)

Comment: Thanks CallumDA. Really helpful. Only question is, the user will input a value in column D first, and then column E. The code currently releases a msgbox when the user enters any value in Column D before there's a value in Column E to compare to

Comment: Add condition to evaluate only if cell in column E is not a null string or empty?

Comment: @S31, I added a condition to ignore if the cell in column E is blank

Comment: @S31, I noticed you wanted it to update from column E as well, so I've updated once again

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @CallumDA is it possible to add to this to also release a different text if the two numbers are equal to each other? And say the discount is equal?

Comment: So this works great, and we can totally stop here if you'd like. My only follow-up question is on your end, it seems like it lists all the cells with errors - on my end, it only provides an error for the current cell with an issue. So as opposed to yours, I'll just get "discount same in cell ___" even though there's other user errors. Is this due to different excel versions?

Comment: @S31, that's just an example of what it looks like if you paste three values (for example) into column D or E. Because when you update more than one value at the same time `Target` is a multi cell range, so the code loops over the range. You can use similar code to loop through all values and return a list of errors when a button is clicked, for example, but that would be a different question ;)

Comment: @CallumDA Thanks for the quick responses - you're the best. Might do that follow-up. Also any great VBA resources for a beginner you might suggest?

Comment: @S31, I learnt from looking at answers on StackOverflow, CodeReview (they *really* know their stuff there) and also a book called Professional Excel Development :)

Comment: @S31 I have a VBA blog with mostly intermediate-advanced content, but I've started a series (currently only 1 post though) about common VBA traps and I'm trying to write it so that beginners aren't massively overwhelmed. See my profile for the links! (feedback from an *actual* VBA beginner would be awesome BTW *wink wink, nudge nudge*)